# Criar array de array já existente

Tags: php, array

Possuo a seguinte linha de código:

```
$valores = implode(", ", array_values($dados));
```

e, ao dar um `var_dump(array($valores));` a seguinte informação é retornada:

> array(1) {
>     [0]=>
>     string(26) "Igor, Teste, i@hotmail.com"
>   }

Porém, preciso que, a cada vírgula, seja retornado cada item em uma nova array (nesse caso, uma array com 3 itens).
Ou seja, seria criar um array dessa outra `array($valores)`.

Qual a melhor maneira de fazer isso?

**EDITADO**

Já tentei utilizar o `explode`:

```
$arrValores = array($valores);
$itemValores = explode(", ", $arrValores);

foreach($itemValores as $item) {
    $item;
}

var_dump($item);
```

Porém, o que me é retornado é:

> string(5) "Array"

**Obrigado!**

Comment: Ou simplesmente não usar o `implode`, apenas o `array_values`.

Comment: Sim, @Sergio. Editei a pergunta.

Comment: @Igor e não usar `implode`?????????

Comment: Pois é, @GuilhermeNascimento. Eu tenho que usar o `implode`, acontece que, era só eu criar outra variável responsável pelo `array_values` somente, e eu nem havia pensado nisso. Obrigado por clarear minha mente!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você necessita usar o `implode`, então você pode declarar duas variaveis, uma para a string formada e outra para a `array`:

```
$valoresArray = array_values($dados);
$valoresStr = implode(", ", $valoresArray);

var_dump($valoresArray);
var_dump($valoresStr);
```